# Changing the "homepage" url for logged-in users

Tags: redirect, redirection

I know I can set  `postLoginRedirect` in config/general.php to send the user to a specific page after login. Is there a way to grab that value in the template? This came up because I noticed that the `{{siteUrl}}` href in the default `_layout.html` template was sending the user to the homepage (index.html), but I'd like to conditionally replace that link for a logged-in user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, something like this should work (untested):

```
<a href="{{ currentUser ? url(craft.config.get('postLoginRedirect')) : siteUrl }}">Home</a>
```

The above should create an absolute URL to whatever's in your `postLoginRedirect` config setting, relative to your `siteUrl`.

Note that if you want an URL relative to your Control Panel (e.g. "dashboard"), you'll want to use `cpUrl()` instead, i.e.

```
<a href="{{ currentUser ? cpUrl(craft.config.get('postLoginRedirect')) : siteUrl }}">Home</a>
```

Comment: Just noticed that with 'postLoginRedirect' => 'dashboard' using the solution above makes the postLoginRedirect a relative link, so it doesn't work on sub-pages. Can you think of a solution besides hard coding an absolute link like 'postLoginRedirect' => '/dashboard'

Comment: @Keith You're correct – just updated the answer with a solution.